# Editing image files with many icons packed into single file

Tags: gratis, image-editor, game-development

There are some games where instead of putting each separate icon into its own file, many icons of the same size are collected together in a single file by tiling them together into a single huge image; the game then uses an index number to grab the correct icon out of the combined image. Is there any image editing tool (or plugin/extension for an existing tool) that would make manipulating such files easier?  The current game I'm interested in modding use BMP files.

**EDIT**: [Here's an example BMP file exhibiting the described behaviour.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2bgrTOo8un5Umg4VVRJSEs0bkk)

Comment: Such files are also used by Stack Overflow, e.g. http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/softwarerecs/img/sprites.svg?v=7b7af3ddab5e